# RefrenceError: Property 'document' doesn't exist. hermes react native

Tags: react-native

i have installed my own custom js library in react native.

But while importing it, i get an error as `RefrenceError: Property 'document' doesn't exist. hermes`.

Library works fine in other js frameworks, i want it to work in react-native as well.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

React Native is not a browser-based framework and does not have a `document`. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but your library will not work in React Native without significant changes.